# Tool to Grab image from video after every 5 seconds

Tags: windows, video, encoding, grab

I want to grab a frame from a video after every 5 seconds. In linux , i found this [post](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2007-November/012232.html) , what are the tools on Windows ? my video is a H264/xvid encoded one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post uses [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) which is "a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video." If you want the bleeding edge ffmpeg you can grab it from the [Automated Unofficial FFmpeg Win32 Builds](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/) page. Or from the [ffmpeg videohelp.com page](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg)